# Can't get data with GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to get data from a mysql database 
but don't return anything. 
Is my first time with Gorm and I have a poor experience with Go.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    "fmt"
)

type productos struct {
    gorm.Model

    id_producto int         `gorm:"type:int, primary_key"`
    stock       int         `gorm:"type:int"`
    codigo      string      `gorm:"type:varchar(45)"`
    rubro       string      `gorm:"type:varchar(100)" `
    descripcion string      `gorm:"type:varchar(140)" `
    proveedores string      `gorm:"type:varchar(250)" `
    moneda      string      `gorm:"type:varchar(10)" `
    costo       float32     `gorm:"type:decimal" `
    iva         float32     `gorm:"type:decimal" `
    pedir       bool        `gorm:"type:tinyint" `
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root:1281@/electronica?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")

    if(err != nil){
        panic(err)
    }else{
        fmt.Println("Conexión obtenida")
    }

    prod := &productos{}

    db.First(&prod)

    fmt.Println(prod.codigo)

    db.Close()
}
```

Comment: Capitalize your struct member field names, like `Stock` instead of `stock`. They are not exported now, so they cannot be set using reflection.

Comment: like this ?

'''
type productos struct {
 gorm.Model

 Id_producto int     `gorm:"type:int, primary_key"`
 Stock       int     `gorm:"type:int"`
 Codigo      string  `gorm:"type:varchar(45)"`
 Rubro       string  `gorm:"type:varchar(100)" `
 Descripcion string  `gorm:"type:varchar(140)" `
 Proveedores string  `gorm:"type:varchar(250)" `
 Moneda      string  `gorm:"type:varchar(10)" `
 Costo       float32 `gorm:"type:decimal" `
 Iva         float32 `gorm:"type:decimal" `
 Pedir       bool    `gorm:"type:tinyint" `
}
'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code snippet:

```
type Productos struct {
    gorm.Model
    // Remove the ProductoID field if you want to use the default gorm Model
    // ProductoID int     `gorm:"type:int, primary_key"`
    Stock       int     `gorm:"type:int"`
    Codigo      string  `gorm:"type:varchar(45)"`
    Rubro       string  `gorm:"type:varchar(100)" `
    Descripcion string  `gorm:"type:varchar(140)" `
    Proveedores string  `gorm:"type:varchar(250)" `
    Moneda      string  `gorm:"type:varchar(10)" `
    Costo       float32 `gorm:"type:decimal" `
    Iva         float32 `gorm:"type:decimal" `
    Pedir       bool    `gorm:"type:tinyint" `
}

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "root:admin123@/test?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    if !db.HasTable(&Productos{}) {
        if err := db.AutoMigrate(&Productos{}).Error; err != nil {
        }
        db.Create(&Productos{
            Stock:       2,
            Codigo:      "a",
            Rubro:       "b",
            Descripcion: "c",
            Proveedores: "d",
            Moneda:      "e",
            Costo:       0,
            Iva:         0,
        })
    }

    producto := &Productos{}
    db.First(producto)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", producto)
}
```

Like @Burak Serdar points out, your fields are not exported (not capitalized), so in your case, they are invisible to `gorm` package

`In Go, a name is exported if it begins with a capital letter. Any "unexported" names are not accessible from outside the package.`

More information from the Tour of Go: [Exported names](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3)

Comment: this is conecting to a existent database with the  columns name in lowercase.
I'm sorry, I'm a noob in go

Comment: @SebastianAlbertoBordi when you migrate the table into the database, the fields will become lowercase. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. My problem was:
I´m incluying the default Gorm model and this isn´t equal to the database and when put it out,that work fine

Realy sorry for my poor english

Comment: did you try the solution that I suggested? I highly recommend it if you are still figuring out about gorm :)